# How to make sure a component fills the available space in html/angular

Tags: html, css, layout

I've an angular application, the angular application has a header, a side menu and a main content.
I'm struggling to have this "main content" taking the full available height.
It's important, because in this view I've a floating action button that need to be on the bottom-right.

I've managed to reproduce the issue here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/sidenav-height-issue?

I've tried to put the height to 100% at several places, without much success. What should I do ?

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `height` of your sidenav container to `100%`

```
<mat-sidenav-container style="height: 100%;">
    <!-- <mat-sidenav #sidenav role="navigation">
    
</mat-sidenav-container>
```